# I need to delete an element in an array everytime a user press , but when is being output after deletion I got long number like ; 124352919

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main ()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75};

    char ans;
    int i = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    cout<<"Press y to generate number"<<"\n";
    cin >> ans;


    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')
    { 
        cout<<"\n\nEnter position to Delete number :: ";
        cin>>pos;

        --pos;

        for(i=pos;i<=size-1;i++)
        {
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            cout<<" "<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\nNew Array is :: \n\n";

        for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
    
        }
      
        cout<<"Press y to generate number"<<"\n";
        cin >> ans;
  
    }
         
    cout << "\n\n";
```

//I need to delete an element in the array ,for example ; if I input position 67 ,it deletes position 67 but when the array is being after deletion , I got 1312123131 at the end

Comment: You cannot _"delete"_ elements from an array???

Comment: `for(i=pos;i<=size-1;i++) {a[i]=a[i+1];` - out of range of array when `i == size - 1` in `a[i + 1]`

Comment: Not elements but the index position I need to delete

Comment: ``size`` is not defined. You should decrement ``size`` after removing an element. Anyway, your code seems incomplete. For example, what's with the second ``for`` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete an element from an array, but you can delete a vector element like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75 };

    char ans;
    int pos = 0;

    cout << "Press y to generate number: ";
    cin >> ans;


    while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter position to Delete number: ";
        cin >> pos;

        --pos;

        nums.erase(nums.begin() + pos);
        cout << "\nNew Array is:\n\n";

        for (const auto& element : nums)
        {
            std::cout << element << '\n';
        }

        cout << "Press y to generate number" << "\n";
        cin >> ans;
    }
}
```